# $user->email cannot be accessed from controller , only works on view

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am working on session data where the email is loaded automatically when user enters new record in grocery crud table. On the top of page , the name /email of current user can be displayed by using (in view folder)

```
<?php echo $user->email;?>
```

However , when I tried using $user->email in the GC controller , it gives me errors even after assigning to a variable. Also tried changing the model by using set_userdata but still wouldnt work. The code is as follows

**Error**

Message: Undefined variable: user

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

**Model**

```
public function takeUser($username, $password)

{

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('user');
  $this->db->where('username', $username);
  $this->db->where('password', $password);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->num_rows();

}

public function userData($username)
{

  $this->db->select('username');
  $this->db->select('name');
  $this->db->select('email');
  $this->db->where('username', $username);
  $query = $this->db->get('user');
  return $query->row();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function program()
{
if($this->session->userdata('isLogin') == FALSE)
{
    redirect('login/login_form');
}
else
{

    $this->load->model('m_login');
    $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level');
    $data['user'] = $this->m_login->userData($user);
}
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('program');
       $crud>columns('nama_program','kod_program','kos_program','rmk','rollingplan','user','email');
    $crud>field_type('nama_program','kod_program','kos_program','rmk','rollingplan','user','email');
    $crud>set_relation('rollingplan','rollingplan','nama_rollingplan');
    $crud->callback_field('user',array($this,'user_field'));
    $crud->callback_field('email',array($this,'email_field'));
    $crud->set_subject('Program Baru');    
    $crud->required_fields('nama_program');
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output_prog($output);
}

function user_field($value = '', $primary_key = null)
{
    return '<input type="text" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly"     value="'.$this->session->userdata('username').'" name="user"     style="width:462px">';
}
function email_field($value = '', $primary_key = null)
{ 
    $mail=$user->email;
    return '<input type="text" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly"      value="'.$mail.'" name="email" style="width:462px">';
}
```

Comment: You must check double this line:
`$user = $this->session->userdata('username');
$data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level');
$data['user'] = $this->m_login->userData($user);}`
Cause you call $user in Controller and send $data['user'] to View, so View will understand that $user is `$data['user'] = $this->m_login->userData($user);`, **not is the user in Controller** `$user = $this->session->userdata('username');`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP version 5.4 or later (I think it works on PHP 5.3 but not sure), you can easily do that with anonymous functions and the `use` keyword. More specifically in your case you can do:

```
public function program() {
    ...
    $crud->callback_field('email',function ($value, $primary_key) use ($user) { 
        return '<input type="text" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" value="'.$user.'" name="email" style="width:462px">';
    });
    ...
}
```

With the above way:

1. The callback is within your function without searching it
2. Your code is more clear
3. It works as you are expecting :)

Comment: That caused an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$crud' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Sorry, I did edit my answer. I forgot to add the `);` at the end

Comment: Message: Trying to get property of non-object error appear for $mail = $user->email;

Comment: Oh well... try use $user :) I am editing again my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->model('m_login');
$user='';
if($this->session->userdata('username'))
{
    $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level');
    $data['user'] = $this->m_login->userData($user);
}
else
{
    //session expired or not created.
}
```

initialize $user with blank and check if session variable exist or not.